# How to get Radio Radio Button Data from POST Request Data in an HTML form?

Tags: python, django, forms, post, request

So I'm coding a test platform consisting of Multiple Choice Questions ( MCQs ) in Django.
Everything is working fine but somehow I think that the radio button value from my question page is not getting fetch via POST request.

Would appreciate some help!

Here are my models :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from .managers import UserManager
from questions.models import Question

class User( AbstractUser ) : 

    email = models.EmailField( verbose_name = 'Email Address', unique = True, null = False )
    username = None

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__( self ) : return self.get_username()



class Student( models.Model ) :

    user = models.OneToOneField( User, on_delete = models.PROTECT )
    mobile = models.CharField( verbose_name = 'Mobile Number', max_length = 10, unique = True )

    def __str__( self ) : return self.user.get_username()


JAVA='J'
PYTHON='P'
DATABASE='D'
OPERATING_SYSTEM='O'
NETWORKING='N'

SUBJECT_CODE = [
    ( JAVA,'java' ),
    ( PYTHON,'python' ),
    ( DATABASE,'database management' ),
    ( OPERATING_SYSTEM,'operating systems' ),
    ( NETWORKING,'Computer Networks' )
]

class Performance( models.Model ) : 

    global SUBJECT_CODE

    student = models.ForeignKey( Student, on_delete = models.PROTECT )
    question = models.OneToOneField( Question, on_delete = models.PROTECT, null = True )

    score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField( verbose_name = 'Score', null = True )
    qno = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField( null = True )
    qindex = models.IntegerField( null = True )
    subject_code = models.CharField( verbose_name = 'Subject Code', max_length = 32, choices = SUBJECT_CODE, default = PYTHON, null = False )
    date_appeared = models.DateField( verbose_name = 'Date of Exam', auto_now_add = True, null = False )
```

```
from django.db import models



EASY='E'
MEDIUM='M'
HARD='H'
DIFFICULTY_LEVEL=[
    (EASY,'easy'),
    (MEDIUM,'medium'),
    (HARD,'hard')
]

A='A'
B='B'
C='C'
D='D'

CORRECT_ANSWER=[(A,'A'),(B,'B'),(C,'C'),(D,'D')]

JAVA='J'
PYTHON='P'
DATABASE='D'
OPERATING_SYSTEM='O'
NETWORKING='N'



SUBJECT_CODE=[
    (JAVA,'java'),
    (PYTHON,'python'),
    (DATABASE,'database management'),
    (OPERATING_SYSTEM,'operating systems'),
    (NETWORKING,'computer networks')
]



class Question( models.Model ) :

    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    subcode=models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SUBJECT_CODE,default=PYTHON,null=False)
    
    q_string=models.CharField(max_length=512,null=False)
    
    A=models.CharField(max_length=512,null=False)
    B=models.CharField(max_length=512,null=False)
    C=models.CharField(max_length=512)
    D=models.CharField(max_length=512)
    
    correct=models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=CORRECT_ANSWER,default=A,null=False)
    difficulty=models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=DIFFICULTY_LEVEL, default=EASY,null=False) 

    def __str__(self): return self.subcode+" "+str(self.id)
```

Here are my views :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from profiles.models import User, Student, Performance
from questions.models import Question
from random import randint

subject_codes = {
    'J' : 'Java',
    'P' : 'Python',
    'O' : 'Operating Systems',
    'N' : 'Computer Networks',
    'D' : 'DBMS'
}


def initialise_test_request( request ) : 

    request.student = Student.objects.get( user = request.user )
    if Performance.objects.filter( student = request.student ).exists() is not True : Performance( student = request.student, subject_code = request.subject_code, score = 0, qno = 1 ).save()

    p = Performance.objects.get( student = request.student )
    
    p.subject_code = request.subject_code
    p.qno = 0
    p.score = 0
    p.qindex = randint( 0, 9 )
    p.question = list( Question.objects.filter( subcode = request.subject_code ) )[ p.qindex ]
    p.save()
    
    return request


def instruction( request, subject_code = None ) :

    if subject_code is not None :
        request.subject_code = subject_code
        request.subject = subject_codes[ subject_code ]

    if request.method == 'POST' : 
        
        if 'test_start' in request.POST.keys() : request = initialise_test_request( request )
        return test( request )

    return render( request, 'instructions.html', {} )

def test( request ) :

    try : p = request.p
    except : p = Performance.objects.get( student = Student.objects.get( user = request.user ) )

    if p.qno > 0 :
        if request.POST[ 'option' ] == list( Question.objects.filter( subcode = p.subject_code ) )[ p.qindex ] : 
            p.score = p.score + 1
            p.save()

    if p.qno == 10 : return render( request, 'score.html', { 'score' : p.score } )
    
    p.qno = p.qno + 1
    p.qindex = randint( 0, 9 )
    p.question = list( Question.objects.filter( subcode = p.subject_code ) )[ p.qindex ]
    p.save()

    request.p = p
    return render( request, 'question.html', { 'p' : p } )
```

Here's my question page :

```
{% extends 'common.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title %}  TEST {% endblock %}

{% block stylesheet %}

    <script type = "text/javascript">

        function submitAndNext()
        {
            var url = 
        }

    </script>

{% endblock %}



{% block body %}

    <center>

        <div>
            {{ p.qno }}. {{ p.question.q_string }}<br>
        </div>

    </center>

    <br>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div  style="margin-left: 50px;">

            <input type="radio" id="" name="option" value="A" required>
            <label for="">{{ p.question.A }}</label>
            <br><br>
            
            <input type="radio" id="" name="option" value="B">
            <label for="css">{{ p.question.B }}</label>
            <br><br>
            
            <input type="radio" id="" name="option" value="C">
            <label for="css">{{ p.question.C }}</label>
            <br><br>
            
            <input type="radio" id="" name="option" value="D">
            <label for="css">{{ p.question.D }}</label>
            <br><br><br>
            
            <input type = "hidden" name = "test_started">
            
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success rounded-pill">Submit and Next</button>

        </div>

    </form>

    {{ p.score }}

{% endblock %}
```

I've been trying different things so there might be some discrepancies.
The score is not getting updated even after clicking the correct Choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an input box is checked this returns 'on'.
Here is what you need:

in views.py

```
if request.method =="POST":
    if request.POST.get('the_name', None) == 'on':
        print(request.POST.get('option'))
if request.method =="POST":
    if request.POST.get('the_name2', None) == 'on':
        print(request.POST.get('option'))
```

in form.html

```
 <input type="radio" name="the_name"/>

 <input type="checkbox" name="the_name2"/>
```